# How can I put this available wordpress theme on my wordpress blog?

Tags: wordpress

This theme http://mnmlist.com/theme/. It doesn't appear on the themes options on my wordpress.com blog dashboard. The instructions seemed to be targeted towards those who operate their own website locally.

Comment: You are sure you have uploaded the upzipped to your wp-contents folder?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Wordpress.com (Hosted WP). If so, you can't add any other theme than the ones available. You need to have your own host in order to install WP with custom themes

Comment: Yes. I'm using wordpress.com; I do not host myself. Are you sure about this? Is there any workaround? Can we make a request to have a theme, in this case this one, to be included in the listing?

Comment: yes, I'm 100% sure, see http://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/adding-new-themes/ and/or http://en.support.wordpress.com/themes/ , it's in wordpress.com support